# openai gpt3.5 api returns 408 error when called from cloud function

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, openai-api

I am using this cloud function and it works for openai davinci model but not for gpt3.5. So in this code exports.gpt3 returns 408 but exports.davinci works just fine

```
const functions = require("firebase-functions");

const { Configuration, OpenAIApi } = require("openai");

const cors = require("cors");

const corsHandler = cors({ origin: true });

const configuration = new Configuration({
apiKey: process.env.OPENAI_API_KEY,
});

const openai = new OpenAIApi(configuration);

exports.gpt3 = functions.https.onRequest(async (request, response) =\> {
corsHandler(request, response, async () =\> {

let messages = [
  { role: "system", content: "You are a helpful assistant." },
  { role: "user", content: "what is the meaning of life" }]

const completionGPT3 = await openai.createChatCompletion({
model: "gpt-3.5-turbo",
messages: messages,
});
console.log(completionGPT3.data.choices\[0\].message);
});
});

exports.davinci = functions.https.onRequest(async (request, response) =\> {
corsHandler(request, response, async () =\> {
const completionDavinci = await openai.createCompletion({
model: "text-davinci-003",
prompt: "How are you",
max_tokens: 100,
temperature: 0.7,
});

response.send(JSON.stringify(completionDavinci.data));

});
});
```

I tried playing with syntax, but could not solve